# How to navigate, with history, in MVC 5 SPA template?

Tags: knockout.js, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, single-page-application

I am struggling with the navigation in the `VS2013 SPA MVC-5` template. I made 2 assumptions (because I couldn't find good references), but it seems I am wrong or it is just not working well:

- It thought that the navigation was be based on the typical `spa # url encoding`, for example to navigate to the `users account management page` directly one should be able to use:`http://localhost:18759/#/manage`
- I also thought that, when navigating across the website (single page) I thought that these `# url's` where formed by the default `knockout.js` files, which are included in the template. Combined with the previous assumption this would result in a proper history build-up.

**`http://localhost:18759/#/manage`** does not seems to navigate to the `manage` page (other `# url's` doesn't work either) .

I noticed some that some frameworks are available to handle this (`navrouter` and `sammy.js`) but as far as I can tell it takes quite some effort to implement them, especially if it's already in place in the template.

As for the reasons why I made these assumptions, there is an article [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1985351.aspx?MVC5%20VS2013%20RC2%20SPA%20Template%20Navigation%20Changes%20), which suggests this is in place due to this part:

```
// app.viewmodel.js - there is a method called "addViewModel()
if (typeof (options.navigatorFactory) !== "undefined") {
        navigator = options.navigatorFactory(self, dataModel);
    } else {
        //suggests "#"-hash navigation
        navigator = function () {
            window.location.hash = options.bindingMemberName;
        };
    }
```

But in my own `app.viewmodel.js` these lines are without reference to the hash at all:

```
if (typeof (options.navigatorFactory) !== "undefined") {
        navigator = options.navigatorFactory(self, dataModel);
    } else {
        navigator = function () {
            self.errors.removeAll();
            self.view(viewItem);
        };
    }
```

There is a reference to the hash in `app.viewmodel.js` here, but this doesn't seem to handle the navigation:

```
// Private operations
function cleanUpLocation() {
    window.location.hash = "";

    if (typeof (history.pushState) !== "undefined") {
        history.pushState("", document.title, location.pathname);
    }
}

function getFragment() {
    if (window.location.hash.indexOf("#") === 0) {
        return parseQueryString(window.location.hash.substr(1));
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

My code to navigate looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li data-bind="with: user"><a href="#" data-bind="click: manage">manage</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the navigation factory is pretty default like:

```
app.addViewModel({
    name: "Manage",
    bindingMemberName: "manage",
    factory: ManageViewModel,
    navigatorFactory: function (app) {
        return function (externalAccessToken, externalError) {
            app.errors.removeAll();
            app.view(app.Views.Manage);

            if (typeof (externalAccessToken) !== "undefined" || 
                typeof (externalError) !== "undefined") {
                   app.manage().addExternalLogin(externalAccessToken, externalError);
            } else {
                app.manage().load();
            };
        }
    }
});
```

**question(s)**

- Should this be working? If so, how can I fix it?
- Or do I need extra components like `sammy.js` or `navrouter`?

Comment: I'm not aware of any routing built in to Knockout. I'm currently using https://github.com/finnsson/pagerjs which is a routing solution designed to be used with Knockout. It's not perfect, but does a pretty good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day of struggling I came to the following conclusion:

- the `#` navigation doesn't seem present in the default `VS2013 MVC 5 SPA template`.

I managed to get it working, so I'll sum up the implementation method here.

Although `pagerjs`, suggested by Paul Manzotti, does the job pretty well, I have chosen to use `sammy.js` to perform the navigation. Other navigation frameworks should work just as well.

So the first step is to get it from `nuget`:

> install-package sammy.js

After the installation of `sammy.js` we need to alter the default `VS2013 MVC 5 SPA template`'s `javascript` files. I'll sum it up:

First enable `sammy.js`. There are various options of where to put the code, but since I want to use it throughout the entire application I putted it in: `~/Scripts/app/_run.js` like this:

```
//_run.js
$(function () {
    app.initialize();

    // Activate Knockout
    ko.validation.init({ grouping: { observable: false } });
    ko.applyBindings(app);

    //provides basic '#' navigation
    //run this function after the initialization of the
    //default knockout code.
    Sammy(function () {
        //"#:view" is the parameter's name of the data after the hash tag 
        //it is stored in "this.params.view"
        this.get('#:view', function () {
            //call the navigation functions
            //these are created in the default knockout initiallization
            app["_navigateTo" + this.params.view]();
        });
    }).run("#Home");//Specify the starting page of your application
 });
```

Next, I wanted the `#` navigation to work "out of the box". A crucial part is that on navigation the `#` parameter is added to the `url` So I needed to hook in the `navigateTo` functions. There is a way in `~/Scripts/app/app.viewmodel.js`:

Change:

```
//app.viewmodel.js
...
// Add navigation member to AppViewModel (for example, app.NavigateToHome());
self["navigateTo" + options.name] = navigator;
```

To:

```
//app.viewmodel.js
...
// Add navigation member to AppViewModel (for example, app.NavigateToHome());
// Override default routing to just set the hash
self["navigateTo" + options.name] = function() {
            window.location.hash = options.name;
    };

    //this one is used by sammy to perform actual default routing
    self["_navigateTo" + options.name] = function() {
        navigator();
    };
```

A final detail has to be fixed, and that is when a user refreshes it's page, the default route will go to `#Home`. This is due to the following code in `~/Scripts/app/app.viewmodel.js`:

```
//app.viewmodel.js
...
self.navigateToLoggedIn = function (userName, accessToken, persistent) {
    self.errors.removeAll();

    if (accessToken) {
        dataModel.setAccessToken(accessToken, persistent)
    }

    self.user(new UserInfoViewModel(self, userName, dataModel));

    //this line only routes to "#Home" when navigation
    //after the login... or register, or something else        
    if (window.location.hash === "#Login" || window.location.hash === "#Register")
        self.navigateToHome();
};
```

So add the proper `if` statement to this code and the `#` is in place.

The proper url to access the manage page will be:

```
http://localhost:18759/#Manage
```

I must say, I haven't had time to give it a proper review (the `#` url encoding might be used elsewhere and may cause collisions). I will update this post if I find some issues.

Another point: of course there are various alternatives in the way to hook into the routing. I have chosen these steps because they work in the case I am working on.